# How can I query Google's Safebrowsing API to check a URL with Python?

Tags: python

I have a list of domains that I need to check for malware. Is there a way I could use Python to query Google's Safebrowsing API to get that information without the need for a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's [Safe Browsing API page](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/) contains a [Python reference client](http://code.google.com/p/google-safe-browsing/downloads/list), take a look at that.